# what's the default background color of gnome-terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-10.04, gnome-terminal

I would like to change the text color to bright green (#66FF00) but keep the default background color ( which is : "use system theme color ") of gnome-terminal. I can customize the text color, but in this case, I still need to specify the background myself. So I would like to know what's the RGB color of the default background color of gnome-terminal (in Ubuntu 10.04), and where I can find this value. Thanks.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/118005/what-are-the-default-layout-settings-in-gnome-terminal

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[ColorPic](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/) kind of softwares will help. These sofwares are able to find out the color on background.

Comment: FOSS alternatives: sudo apt-get install gpick gcolor2

Answer (score 11):

Since at least 12.10, probably much earlier ([source](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-art-pkg/ubuntu-themes/trunk/annotate/head:/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/gnome-terminal.rc#L37) goes back to 2010-08), in Ambiance and Radiance themes, it's [`#300A24`](https://www.colorcodehex.com/300a24/).
Defined in: `/usr/share/themes/*/gtk-*/apps/gnome-terminal*`.
Note that it's also slightly transparent (if compositing is enabled) - 5% if I'm reading the config right.

I was somewhat surprised that it's not one of the standard colors from [Canonical's aubergine/orange palette](http://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette).

Answer (score 2):

or simply a screenshot opened in GIMP, then pressing either 'O' or clicking the foreground color on the toolbar, picking the eyedropper.
you'd have to adjust the code then, simply adding a '#' in front of it.

another way would be to install GEANY, which is a very nice text / script editor anyway, and then using the tools>color chooser, then the eyedropper. which lets lets you click anywhere, like on the desktop, and returns the HEX value, complete with '#', and also in upper-case letters.

Answer (score 2):

For ubuntu terminal background RGB is (48, 10, 36). and Hex Color Code is #300A24